# Phpstorm doesn't indent new lines on enter

Tags: php, phpstorm

Code inside `<?php ?>` doesn't always get indented in PhpStorm. It acts like this:

```
<?php
  echo 's';//PRESS ENTER
//caret jumps here

  if($boolean){//PRESS ENTER
    //caret jumps here(as expected)
  }
?>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: The default setup is that it doesn't indent if it isn't in a code block. You did a manual indent after the tags but PHPStorm doesn't recognise that as a place where it needs to indent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, PHP code is only indented in a code block (`{...}` or an array definition, like `array(...)`). In other words, by default, PHPStorm formats code like this:

```
<?php
echo 's';//PRESS ENTER
//caret jumps here

if($boolean){//PRESS ENTER
    //caret jumps here(as expected)
}
?>
```

To make it indent inside the `<?php ... ?>` tags, go to Preferences > Editor > Code Style > PHP > Other and check "Indent code in PHP tags", like this:

[image: PHPStorm PHP Code Style configuration screenshot]

You can see both the check box and the resulting formatting in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

I have some few updated code with [PHPStorm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4N_pOk6aCUZUU91YlVSSlQtSkE/view?usp=sharing).

Import this setting to yours. It has lot features associate with this.

> 1. Php
> 2. SQL
> 3. CSS
> 4. JS

Comment: Already solved the problem(check accepted answer). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Its ok. this for extra knowledge.

Comment: @Abdulla You appear to be offering a general set of settings for import, with styles relevant to four different languages, but you haven't specified what those style settings are. It's unlikely that OP wants to import all of those settings without knowing what they are. Also, you haven't actually answered the question: how can OP change this particular setting? Your answer is really a link-only answer.

Comment: @EdCottrell if you actully import that you can check that. Ther is alingment fixed in all mentioned languages aa well as coloring project. And etc etc. Export ur current 1n and try mine. You can feal it..thanx for your idea

Comment: @Abdulla I'm not about to import anyone else's settings, either. That's kind of the point. Your answer doesn't say how to solve OP's question; instead, it offers up a ton of stuff OP may not want. People have different preferences regarding indentation, coloring, etc. OP probably doesn't want to use all of your settings. Nor do I; I need my code to comply with the styles I have already specified for myself.